# Unable to resolve service for ApplicationDbContext while attempting to activate <projectdirectory>.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, startup

I am new to dotnet core and following through a course. Using visual studio on mac. I had some hard times to use scaffolding functionality. now I figured one mistake. fixed it. and it gives me another warning.

Output for Error:

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[leave_management.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationDbContext]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'leave_management.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.

Regular ApplicationDbContext file includes following code:

```
    namespace leave_management.Data
    {
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public DbSet<LeaveRequest> LeaveRequests { get; set; }

        public DbSet<LeaveType> LeaveTypes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<LeaveAllocation> LeaveAllocations { get; set; }
        
      }
   }
```

i am using entity framework, so the inherited ApplicationDbcontext includes following:

```
namespace leave_management.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Employee>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The Program.cs includes following:

```
namespace leave_management
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}

namespace leave_management
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            // Adding references for Repository and Contracts to Startup file 
            services.AddScoped<ILeaveTypeRepository, LeaveTypeRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ILeaveRequestRepository, LeaveRequestRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ILeaveAllocationRepository, LeaveAllocationRepository>();

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Maps)); 

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<Employee>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>() ;

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); 
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app,
            IWebHostEnvironment env,
            UserManager<Employee> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
            )
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            SeedData.Seed(userManager, roleManager);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I have seen a post similar to this one, it was not pretty similar problem, I had hard times to follow the documentation. That is why I am posting here. I appreciate your help. Best regards.

Comment: Can you post your startup file as well, pls

Comment: Thank you Serge. It is included above now.